# Add sections dynamically to card

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm new on Apps Script and I'm a bit lost, is there a way to add dynamically a section on a card? I'm trying this:

```
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(peekHeader)
      .addSection(section).build();

  card.addSection(sectionTo);
```

And I'm getting `TypeError: card.addSection is not a function`

If I try:

```
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(peekHeader)
      .addSection(section);

  card.addSection(sectionTo).build();
```

I get another error:

```
The value returned from Apps Script has a type that cannot be used by the add-ons platform. Also make sure to call build on any builder before returning it. Value: values {
  struct_value {
  }
}
```

Update:

Sections are defined like:

```
  var section = CardService.newCardSection()
                  .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("The email is from: " + from));
  var sectionTo = CardService.newCardSection()
                  .addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText("To: " + to));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Once a card has been built, unfortunately it cannot be modified anymore.

If e.g. on an event you want to change the card content - you need to build and return a new card that would replace the old one.

The correct way to build the card would be

```
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder() 
  .setHeader(peekHeader)
  .addSection(section)
  .addSection(sectionTo)//; // or using section card.addSection(sectionTo); // or using section 
  .build();
```

If instead you try to apply

```
card.addSection(sectionTo).build();
```

to

```
 var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(peekHeader)
      .addSection(section);
```

the variable `card` will represent a section - and adding a section to a section will give you an error.

Comment: But then why the second option doesn't work, I don't get it.

Comment: How is `sectionTo` defined?

Comment: Updated question with sections definition.

Comment: If you replace the variables `from` and `to` through hardcoded strings, do you still get the same error?

Comment: How is `peekHeader` defined? Does `var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(peekHeader)
      .addSection(section).build();` work for you?

Comment: Yes, now I was checking it again and if I try:

  `var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  card.setHeader(peekHeader);
  card.addSection(sectionTo);  // or using section
  card.addSection(sectionTo);  // or using section
  card.build();`

works. but If I mixes `section` and `sectionTo`. It doesn't.

Comment: Got was wrong. Updating question. Thanks for your help @ziganotschka

Comment: See my updated answer - I think you came to the same conclusions!

Answer (score 0):

As @ziganotschka was saying, after building a card, this card cannot be modified. When you do `CardService.newCardBuilder()`, you are creating an object with type `CardBuilder`, but when you do `built()`, return object was type `Card`, so you cannot longer do `.addSection` over my object card (with type `Card`).

On the second code, `addSection` is properly done, but since return object from `.build()` is not save anywhere and after that I'm returning card object (still type `CardBuilder`), it is causing the second error. That's why, now I get it:

```
The value returned from Apps Script has a type that cannot be used by the add-ons platform. Also make sure to call build on any builder before returning it.
```

Answer (score 0):

As @ziganotschka mentioned, you can't change the card structure once is built.
But you can replace a card with another one, containing the changes you want.
I create a small example that might help someone in the future.
Basically, every time you click on the button "ADD NEW INPUT", it adds a new TextInput input widget. It also maintain the TextInputs's values when replacing the cards.

```js
function onHomepageTrigger(e) {  
  var builder = CardService.newCardBuilder();

  addTextInputSection(builder, e);
        
  return builder.build();
}

function addTextInputSection(builder, e) {
  let numberOfInputs = 1;
  if (e.hasOwnProperty("parameters") && e.parameters.hasOwnProperty("numberOfInputs")) {
    numberOfInputs = parseInt(e.parameters.numberOfInputs);
  }

  let formInputs = e.formInputs;
  if (!e.hasOwnProperty("formInputs")) {
    formInputs = {};
  }

  const section = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('<b>HEADER</b>');

  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfInputs; i++) {
    let fieldName = 'ticker_input_' + i;
    let value = '';
    if (formInputs.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
      value = formInputs[fieldName][0];
    }

    const tickerInput = CardService.newTextInput().setFieldName(fieldName).setValue(value).setTitle('Ex: ...').setMultiline(false);
    section.addWidget(tickerInput);
  }

  const action = CardService.newAction()
    .setFunctionName('onAddTextInputClicked')
    .setParameters({numberOfInputs: (numberOfInputs + 1).toString()});

  const button = CardService.newTextButton()
    .setText('ADD NEW INPUT')
    .setOnClickAction(action)
    .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.TEXT);
  section.addWidget(button);

  builder.addSection(section);
}

function onAddTextInputClicked(e) {

  var navigation = CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(onHomepageTrigger(e));
  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNavigation(navigation).build();
}
```